# Checking independence between sigma algebra and a random variable

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

$(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$:Probability space

$Y:$ Random variable

When using these setups and defining $\eta \equiv Y - E[Y| \mathcal{F}]$,

I want to show that a random variable $\eta$ and $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ are indipendent.

To prove the statement,  a textbook says you need to show that for all $A \in \mathcal{F}$,

\begin{align}
E[\eta 1_A[x]] = E[\eta]E[1_A[x]]
    \end{align}
where $1_A[x]$ is a indicator function of A

Is it correct to introduce to the following statements by the definitions of independent in probability theory?

"a random variable $\eta$ and $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ are independent”　(1)

$\Leftrightarrow$ "$\sigma$($\eta$) and $\mathcal{F}$ are independent” (2)

$\Leftrightarrow$ "for all A $\in$ $\mathcal{F}$, $\sigma$($\eta$) and $\sigma(1_A[x])$ are independent” (3)

$\Leftrightarrow$ "for all A $\in$ $\mathcal{F}$,  random variables $\eta$ and $1_A[x]$ are independent” (4)

$\Leftrightarrow$ "for all A $\in$ $\mathcal{F}$, E[$\eta1_A[x]$] = E[$\eta$]E[$1_A[x]$]" (5)

Comment: The last one works only one way. $E(UV)=(EU)(EV)$ is only a necessary condition for independence. It is not sufficient. The text book also seems to have made an error.

Comment: Your assumption gives $\mathbb E[Y\mid \mathcal F]=Y$, so I'm not so sure about your statement.

Comment: Thanks. 
"E(UV)=(EU)(EV) is only a necessary condition"
You means (1) ~ (4) are equivalent and (4) => (5) holds, but (4) <= (5) is false. don't you? I overlook that and I think you are right.

Comment: Thanks " E[Y∣F]=Y" Could you tell me how to introduce? From my assumption, $E[E[Y∣F]]=E[Y]$ holds by iterated conditioning, but I think  " E[Y∣F]=Y" doesn't seem hold.

Answer (score 0):

With your definitions $\eta =0$ so there is nothing to prove. If, however, $\mathcal F$ is not the original sigma algebra on $\Omega$ (but some sub-sigma algebra of it)  then this result is not true. Let $Y \sim N(0,1)$ and let $\mathcal F$ be the sigma algebra a generated by $Y^{2}$. Then $\eta =Y$ and $Y$ is not independent of $Y^{2}$.